# Calculating voting power indexes in R

Tags: r, function, permutation, voting-system

I have a project in which i need to be able to calculate different voting power indexes in R. As a first attempt at this I wrote a small function to calculate the banzhaf index. It takes two arguments, a dataframe that has two columns which must be labelled member and vote, and how many votes are needed for a majority (quota):

```
library(combinat)
banzhaf <- function(data,quota){
 f <- vector()
 m <- vector()
 score <- vector()
 name <- vector()
 pivot <- vector()
 for (n in 1:nrow(data)){
  y <- as.matrix(combn(data$member,n))
  for (i in 1:ncol(y)){
   for ( j in 1:n){
    f[j] <- data[data$member == y[j,i],]$vote
    m[j] <- as.character(data[data$member == y[j,i],]$member)
    o <- data.frame(member = m, vote = f)
    }

   if (sum(o$vote) >= quota){
    for (k in 1:length(o$member)){
     t <- o[-k,]
    if (sum(t$vote) < quota){
     pivot[length(pivot) + 1] <- as.character(o$member[k])
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }

 for (l in unique(pivot)){
  score[length(score) + 1] <- sum(pivot == l)
  name[length(name) + 1] <- l
  }
 out <- data.frame(name = name, score = score/length(pivot))
 return(out)
}
```

The problem with this function is that it becomes incredibly slow when i have more than 8 members in the dataframe. This is due to the combn() function used in the outermost loop (I think). Does anyone know how this can be made to run faster?

Best, Thomas

P.S: If you want to test it use the following data, but beware that it might run forever!

```
x <- c("Germany","France","UK","Italy","Spain","Poland","Romania","Netherlands","Greece","Portugal","Belgium","Czech Rep.","Hungary","Sweden","Austria","Bulgaria","Denmark","Slovakia","Finland","Ireland","Lithuania","Latvia","Slovenia","Estonia","Cyprus","Luxembourg","Malta")
z <- c(29,29,29,29,27,27,14,13,12,12,12,12,12,10,10,10,7,7,7,7,7,4,4,4,4,4,3)

dat <- data.frame(member = as.character(x),vote = z)

oi <- banzhaf(dat, 255)
oi
```

Comment: Four nested `for` loops?  Oh wow.  That's four too many.

Comment: The function doesn't work because `piv` is not defined in `score[length(piv) + 1]`.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, I renamed some of the vectors when posting it for readability, I forgot to change that one. Done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach was similar to David's, using batched matrix operations to handle the size:

```
banzhaf = function(votes, pass=sum(votes) %/% 2 + 1, batch.size=500000, quiet=batches == 1) {
  n = length(votes)
  batches = ceiling((2^n / batch.size))
  if (!quiet)
    cat('calculating...\n')
  Reduce(`+`, lapply(1:batches, function(b) {
    if (!quiet)
      cat('-', b, '/', batches, '\n')
    i = ((b - 1) * batch.size + 1):min(2^n, b * batch.size)
    m = do.call(cbind, lapply(as.integer(2^((1:n) - 1L)), function(j, k) (k %/% j) %% 2L, i))
    x = drop(m %*% votes)
    passed = x >= pass
    colSums((outer(x[passed] - pass, votes, `<`) * m[passed, , drop=F]))
  }))
}
```

Uses R's name propagation instead of a data.frame, avoid loops where possible, and use integers instead of numerics if possible. Still took over 6 minutes to run on my box:

```
# wikipedia examples
banzhaf(c(A=4, B=3, C=2, D=1), 6)
banzhaf(c('Hempstead #1'=9, 'Hempstead #2'=9, 'North Hempstead'=7, 'Oyster Bay'=3, 'Glen Cove'=1, 'Long Beach'=1), 16)

# stackoverflow data
system.time(banzhaf(setNames(as.integer(z), x), 255))
```

The thinking went something like:

- 2^n possible outcomes (2 outcomes per player, n independent players)
- represented by the numbers the 1:2^n (cf 'i')
- expressing the number in binary gives each player's vote.
- using modulus and division to extract the bits into a voting matrix (cf 'm'), in lieu of bitwise ops (only added to R recently I believe).

After that I think it plays out in the same manner as David's. The only complication was ensuring use of integers for efficiency, and adding the batching as its not really feasible to create a matrix of 27:2^27!

Comment: Could you say more about what this code is doing, particularly this bit?

Comment: this bit: lapply(as.integer(2^((1:n) - 1L)), function(j, k) (k %/% j) %% 2L, i)

Comment: Cool. Good to have this method in mind for extracting bits. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Your example data frame has 27 rows and you're looking at every set (except the null set) so that's 2^27 - 1 = 134 217 727 operations at least... this is going to take some time. That said, here's what I believe to be a more efficient version of your code. It seems to match the Wikipedia article at least: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banzhaf_power_index

```
banzhaf1 <- function(data, quota) {
  n <- nrow(data)
  vote <- data$vote
  swingsPerIndex <- numeric(n)
  for (setSize in 1:n) {
    sets <- utils::combn(n, setSize)
    numSets <- ncol(sets)
    flatSets <- as.vector(sets)
    voteMatrix <- matrix(vote[flatSets], nrow=setSize, ncol=numSets)
    totals <- colSums(voteMatrix)
    aboveQuota <- totals >= quota
    totalsMatrix <- matrix(rep(totals, each=setSize), nrow=setSize, ncol=numSets)
    winDiffs <- totalsMatrix[, aboveQuota] - voteMatrix[, aboveQuota]
    winSets <- sets[, aboveQuota]
    swingers <- as.vector(winSets[winDiffs < quota])
    swingsPerIndex <- swingsPerIndex + tabulate(swingers, n)
  }
  return(data.frame(name=data$member, score=swingsPerIndex / sum(swingsPerIndex)))
}
```

(I haven't tried running this on the full data set.)

I think to really approach this problem efficiently, you'll have to take advantage of the structure of the problem. For instance, once you know set X has vote sum above quota, then you know that X union Y is also above quota. I'm not sure if R will be well-suited to following such structure.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for resurrecting this post, but there's a more efficient algorithm (than trying all coalitions) to compute the Banzhaf index using dynamic programming that it would be good to note for future readers. [[1](https://www.nii.ac.jp/TechReports/public_html/03-006E.pdf)]

The general idea is that the count of decisive coalitions can be rewritten into a form which can be calculated in `O(nq)` time, where `n` is the number of voters and `q` is the quota.

---

NOTE: I'm using 1-indexing, as is common math convention. You'll have to shift things round a little if you want to use 0-indexing.

Let

```
L(i) = { 1, 2, ..., i }
U(i) = { i, i+1, ..., n }.
```

Let `w(i)` be the vote weight of voter `i`, and `w(S)` be the set of vote weights of every voter in `S`.

The number of decisive coalitions is specified by

```
D(i) = |{S : S ⊆ p ∧ i∉S ∧ ( q - w(i) ≤ ∑w(S) < q ) }|.
```

That is, the number of coalitions that do not meet quota without i, but would meet quota if `i` were added.

We can break the coalitions into upper and lower voter sets like this:

```
|{S : S ⊆ p ∧ i∉S ∧ ( q - w(i) ≤ ∑w(S ∩ L(i)) + ∑w(S ∩ U(i)) < q ) }|
```

as `S` doesn't include `i`. Further, that is in turn equal to

```
|{S : S ⊆ p ∧ ( q - w(i) ≤ ∑w(S ∩ L(i-1)) + ∑w(S ∩ U(i+1)) < q ) }|.
```

However, we know `L(i-1))` and `U(i+1)` don't overlap, so we can just choose two sets `S1` and `S2` such that

```
|{(S1,S2) : S1 ⊆ L(i-1) ∧ S2 ⊆ U(i+1) ∧ ( q - w(i) ≤ ∑w(S1) + ∑w(S2)) < q ) }|.
```

Lastly, we can break up the tuple set like this

```
∑[y : q-w(i)≤y<q] |{S : S ⊆ L(i-1) ∧ ∑w(S) = y}| *
  (∑[z : max(q-w(i)-y,0)≤z<q] |{S : S ⊆ U(i+1) ∧ ∑w(S) = z}|)
```

Those particular bounds on the sums are there to guarantee that

```
q - w(i) ≤ y + z < q.
```

This is where the key insight comes in. We can precompute the set counts

```
l(i, y) = |{S : S ⊆ L(i-1) ∧ ∑w(S) = y}|
u(i, z) = |{S : S ⊆ U(i+1) ∧ ∑w(S) = z}|
```

in O(nq) time, as

```
l(1, y)   = (if y = 0 then 1 else 0)
l(i+1, y) = l(i, y) + (if y ≥ w(i) then l(i, y-w(i)) else 0)

u(i-1, z) = u(i, z) + (if y ≥ w(i) then u(i, y-w(i)) else 0)
u(n, z) = (if z = 0 then 1 else 0)
```

It also helps to compute the sums of `u` all at once; define

```
us(i, 0)   = u(i, 0)
us(i, z+1) = u(i, z+1) + us(i, z)
```

You only ever need to compute these for `y` and `z` less than the quota, so you just allocate three tables of size `n * q`, compute `l`, `u`, and `us`, then return

```
∑[y : q-w(i)≤y<q] l(i, y) * ( us(i, q-1) - us(i, max(q-w(i)-y,0)) )
```